# Branch prediction between objects of same class

Tags: c++, class, optimization, branch

I'm optimizing a program, and trying to avoid branch misprediction. I have two objects of a class. In the class's primary function there are several `if` branches. Each object takes a different direction on each of those branches, and they each run the function one after another. My questions:

Since they're members of the same class, and are therefore sharing that function, are they also sharing the same branch prediction? Essentially, am I making the system go TFTFTFTF...

Or, since they're their own objects do they have their own branch predictions and therefore maintaining consistent predictions (TTTTTTT... and FFFFFFFF...)

Comment: Brand prediction? Like Coke or Pepsi? Apple or PC? I predict that OS/2 will be the operating system of the future.

Comment: @KerrekSB You did not hear? Brand is the singular form of branches. Might be somewhere buried in the C++11 spec.

Comment: @Joe: I forgot about that -- all those redefinitions. I hear there are no more "sequence points", and `auto` is now `car`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the method is shared between instances of a class.

It means, as well, that the predictions are shared.

However, there is more to branch prediction than the "last" time. The processor will remember some of the last results and identify "easy" (cyclic) patterns. Therefore, if you constantly swap between your two objects and the pattern ends up `TFTFTFTFTF` then the processor will correctly guess that the next result will be a `T`.

From a semantic point of view, however, did you thought about using a base class and two different derived classes (+ the usual virtual mechanism) ?

Comment: Huh. That's interesting. And no, I hadn't thought about the derived method. That's another option I'm definitely going to consider. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother about such low-level details like [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction) (it will vary from one model of a processor to the next). Leave that optimization to the compiler (and it is probably good enough).

If you want to improve your application, work more on the algorithms themselves. And use profiling & measurements. Don't forget that **premature optimization is evil**.

Comment: Well I'm finished getting the software to work, so now the next logical step is improving it's cycle use, because as of right now it's way too high. And though the main part of my optimization work is focused on better algorithms, this particular loop is called so many times that I need to reduce the branch misprediction. I'm just not sure if indeed misprediction is occurring, hence my original question.

Comment: @Henley: use a decent profiler to see where the bottlenecks *really* are and whether branch misprediction is an issue - I'm betting it's not and that you have much bigger performance issues to worry about before you get down to these tiny micro-optimisations.

Comment: That's good advice, and it is on my to-do list. The reason i bring it up now is because I'm in the middle of rewriting a big chunk of the program for structural reasons, and since I have multiple paths to take (to if or not to if) I figured it was best to determine this now. P.S. I'm using XCode. Is it's profiler considered "decent"?

Answer (score 2):

Since a branch misprediction will typically cost of the order of 10 to 20 cycles it's really only of importance when it's inside a loop that is being executed millions of times a second. Modern CPUs do a pretty good job of branch prediction anyway, so it's pretty rare to have to worry about this kind of thing (compared to say 5 - 10 years ago).

Comment: My program is a synthesizer, and this particular function is called so many times per second, that is conventional wisdom among audio DSP programmers, to avoid branch misprediction within this loop. So in my case, though I know it's rare, I do need to address this.

Comment: @Hanley: unless you need this to run on very old CPUs then you probably don't need to worry - optimisation mythology tends to persist  long past its "best before date".